# Magento 2.3.0 custom cron job is not working

Tags: module, magento2.3, magento-cron

Magento 2 custom corn is not working in my custom module.

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/crontab.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">

<group id="default">
    <job name="review_reminder_cronjob" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Cron\ReminderEmail" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Cron/ReminderEmail.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Cron;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ReminderEmail
{
    /**
    * Write to system.log
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public function execute()
    {        
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Test cron worked successfully');
    }
}
```

Run below command :

> php bin/magento cron:run

Something is missing or wrong in the code above. can anyone help me to solve out this?

I have already tried below way.

- [HOW TO SET AND CONFIGURE CUSTOM CRON JOBS IN MAGENTO 2?](https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-set-and-configure-custom-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/)
- [Configure a custom cron job and cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html)

### **Edit :** In my database cron status is **Missed** or **Error**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please specify "not working"

Comment: </config> is missing in the XML. therefor it's not valid

Comment: is the module enabled? did you run setup:upgrade and clear the caches?

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: @PhilippSander It's a typo mistake. I changed it. yes, a module is enabled.

Comment: @AveshNaik Linux OS.

Comment: Did you set cron job?

Comment: @KamleshSolanki from where i can set cron job?

Comment: did you worked on local machine?

Comment: working in Local machine.

Comment: again: please specify "not working" in your question

Comment: @Philipp he didn't setup the cron, that why it's not working.

Comment: run the magento cron:run command a few more times and check again

Comment: @PhilippSander i changed not working in my question.

Comment: @AveshNaik I run `setup:upgrade` then clear cache and run `php bin/magento cron:run --group default`  cron is working. but in database status of cron is `missed`

Comment: remove front slash `(\)` from `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;` to `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`;

Comment: @AmitBera I was changed and I also update my question. can you please check and give me an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: Your job name is `test_reminder_cronjob`  but as per as ,your screenshot your job name is different

Comment: It is  a typo mistake. cron job name is `review_reminder_cronjob`

Comment: is magento cron  working at magento 2?  change cronjob time every min to 10mins .see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Setting cron job in Linux server using below command.

1) Check cron are set or not using below command.

```
crontab -l
```

2) Going to magento root Set cron job using below command.

```
php bin/magento cron:install -f
```

Comment: @ChiragPatel is this help for setup cronjob?